# Reading User system name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

Hello I have app running on the server. In app I use windows auth but for unknown reason for me it always returns server login instead of user.

Eg:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li class="navbar-text">Hello, @Environment.UserName!</li>
</ul>
```

This should show: Hello szpicus but it returns : Hello, System (page on the server is running with NT/System rights)

How to modify code to recognize users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for this:

```
//on the local machine use this
string domainName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

//on the publishing server use this
string domainName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
string name = domainName.Substring(domainName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
```

Comment: It looks promising but It returns Login with domain. Is there way to get without it or just implement code to cut domain?

Comment: I don't know of any method/property to return the identity without the domain (which does not mean it doesn't exist). Removing the domain is fairly trivial. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Ok I only needed to modify slightly code because it returns \\szpicus instead of just szpicus but thanks!

Comment: @szpic, glad I could help. I updated the code, it should be better now.

Comment: Sorry I need to uncheck this. On the local server its working but when published on the remote server it shows NTAUthority\System instead of login

Comment: @szpic, should have included both. Updated the answer. I usually check both while developing/testing.